# I get a "connect to sql server" message when running query in visual studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

My sql server service was running fine but just yesterday, I stopped the service to quickly delete some databases it was using and ever since the instance will not run.
Giving me the error;

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to master.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

The network path was not found
```

I have tried reinstalling sql server 2008 but to no avail.
SQL Server services are all running

Comment: Any chance that the default Database your connection string specifies is one of the databases that you deleted?

Comment: What exactly did you delete, and how?

Comment: Search for "SQL Server Configuration Manager" in the search tab>>
Then in the "SQL Server Services" look for "SQL Server" is in Running state or not? If not then start it...
Hope it solves your issue...

Comment: This happens in the connect dialog box when I go to Tools -> SQL Server -> New Query... before I even start entering in a query. The process is not running as usual in Task Manager. I deleted the database because I ran the script under the wrong directory rerunning would not allow me to use the same name.  In my services I only have one SQL service, 'SQL Server VSS Writer' and its running.
The SQL Server Configuration Manager shows no services under "SQL Server Services". I have SQL Server 2014 and 2016 installed